# Looker date pivot is not working as expected

Tags: pivot, pivot-table, looker

I am having an issue with pivots by date. When I try to add a pivot by date it ends up stacking month over month.

All the percentages are correct for each month showing and they line up with the correct names but for some reason its stacking.

I did try to remove the date from the table and then add it as a pivot but for some reason I get this odd stacking behavior.

[image]

I suspect it might be due to the way the custom measures work since I have not seen this happen with a normal measure before.

[image]

See example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the solution was to change the data in the view from a dimension to a measure and to change the type from a number to a sum.

After doing this to both fields I am using for creating the percentage it corrected the way the pivot was displayed.

[image]

Results:

[image]